# Should I use Postgres' JSON columns for additional related data of different types and not yet known?

Tags: postgresql, schema, json, architecture, relations

I have a simple database table, lets call it `tbl_main` with a few columns and relations to other tables via foreign keys.

The `tbl_main` is the most frequently written to table, as in it receives new rows (not so much updating existing rows).

The application should be able to support **various additional data related to this table** that adds valuable information to the entries in `tbl_main`.

Yet it is not known ahead of time what kind of information this will be.
E.g. it can simply be a value, an array or an object/document or a combination of those types.

(When) Should I

- create several new JSON columns for each new related kind of data or
- create one JSON column for every kind of related data or
- create a new table referencing the main table via foreign key (possibly via another junction table) for every new related data or
- create one separate meta table `tbl_main_meta` that has a foreign key relationship and one binary column for the additional data?

I would like to keep the database architecture and the application architecture extensible for future data that is related to this `tbl_main`, yet it **should be easy/efficient in the application to query for this additional data and to process it for multiple queried rows of `tbl_main`**.

Example:

- additional data is only one integer value (may be null) and should be summed up.
- additional data is a list of integer values with different units, each unit's values should be summed up for all queried rows of `tbl_main`
- additional data are multiple documents that should be both summed up for unit's values but also returned if there are string entries

The answer could also be that I must evaluate this for every new related data that I want to support, but then how should a general design look like, because I assume the meta_table approach is bad practice/inefficient?

Comment: I would go for a single JSONB column.